# Accessing RAISEERROR message from cfstoredproc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, coldfusion, raiserror, cfstoredproc

I have a SQL stored procedure which under some situations will return a result of -1 if it fails, but also returns a message via the RAISERROR command e.g.:

```
BEGIN

    RAISERROR ('Error %i has occurred', 11, 1, 0)
    RETURN -1

END
```

I am accessing this via coldfusion using cfstoredproc e.g.:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="sp_return" datasource="myDatasource" returncode="yes">
<cfdump var="#cfstoredproc#">
```

But the structure returned only contains an ExecutionTime and StatusCode keys. Is there any way I can access the error message which has been returned. e.g. To display to the user.

Thanks,

Tom

p.s. I would tag with "cfstoredproc" but I can't create new tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what DB you use but with Oracle I just use ColdFusion Exceptions to bubble up the Oracle exceptions. - #cfcatch.message# and #cfcatch.detail# are what you want to echo to the user.

```
<cftry>

<cfstoredproc  procedure = "my_Proc" dataSource = "#DB#" returnCode = "No">
   <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" variable="myvar"   value="#someval#" null="No"> 
   <cfprocresult name="my_Response">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfcatch type="any">

   <cflog file="ProcError" text="Message = #cfcatch.message# Detail= #cfcatch.detail#">

</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005. When I try wrapping a cftry/cfcatch block around my code it makes no difference - no coldfusion error is thrown so there's nothing to catch I guess.

Comment: I confirm that using SQL Server 2005 and Adobe CF 8 a DO recieve raised error in cfcatch.Detail: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Error 0 has occurred

Comment: @Loftx - Seems odd but there is a setting in "Debug Output Settings" under "Custom Debugging Output" about showing exception info in debugging. I use the technique in servers with robust debugging off but that field may need to be checked. Is it on your box?

Comment: That severity 11 in RAISERROR is important; ColdFusion seems to ignore anything 10 and under, but 11 will cause an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **cfprocresult**? [Manual page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_p-q_15.html#1102246) says:

> Associates a query object with a
>   result set returned by a stored
>   procedure.

Comment: Hi, I tried the query in my original response with a cfprocresult. When dumping out this variable I get a variable undefined error.

From reading the docs it looks like this is for returning querys whereas my stored procedure returns -1 and the error message.

Comment: See, you have to do the SELECT to populate this variable, for example "SELECT 'this is error text' AS error". I'm not a SQL server guru, but I suppose it is possible to handle the error in the procedure and return the result using SELECT.